# How to prove that the mapping of the braid to the Automorphism group of the free group is a complete invariant?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Does anybody know how to prove that the mapping of the braid to the free group's automorphism group is a complete invariant?

Comment: It would improve the quality of your question if you add more detail, for example a description or a reference to a description of the $B_n\to \operatorname{Aut}(F_n)$ map.

Comment: @KyleMiller I don't have anything to reference unfortunately. sorry!

Comment: It's not clear, for example, if you are also asking what the mapping is.  It would improve the question if you add what you do and do not know.

Comment: @KyleMiller I'm given this as a stand alone problem and it is out of context for me. I tried to rephrase the problem. hope this clarifies things. thank you for your comment as well.

Comment: It is not even clear from your question what a complete invariant means. Do you mean that a homomorphism is jinjective? In any case, you should write what your thoughts are and what you know about the problem. For now, VTC.